# How to import JSON file to javascript array

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am working on a node project that needs a list of JSON objects. At first, I copy and pasted the entire list of JSON into the main app.js file but clearly that isn't conventional. I made a new json file with all the objects I need in my models folder and am accessing it like this

```
var subjects = require('./models/courses.json');
```

When I console.log this, it throws an error

```
Unexpected token , in JSON at position 52
```

I basically just want to be able to make subjects store an array of json objects.

Here is my json file

```
{"id" : "AAFS",   "department" : "Africana Studies"},
{"id" : "AANT",   "department" : "Anthropology"},
{"id" : "AARA",   "department" : "Arabic"},
{"id" : "AARH",   "department" : "Art History"},
{"id" : "AART",   "department" : "Art"}
```

Comment: Just read it using `fs` functions.

Comment: Would you mind posting the JSON file?

Comment: That error indicates your file isn't proper JSON. Note [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/JSON) is stricter than JavaScript object literals. You can't have trailing commas, keys must be enclosed in strings, and a whole host of stricter rules. To convert an object to JSON, use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you have poorly formed JSON.

Paste it here to see if it validates: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Chances are that it is whatever comes before that comma.

Comment: This is my first guess too.  You might have a trailing comma, which would be tolerated in a script tag, but not when you're importing it.    e.g. `[123,456,]`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a JSON with a set of objects, you need to create an array to wrap the objects, so I suppose this should solve your problem:

```
[
  {"id" : "AAFS",   "department" : "Africana Studies"},
  {"id" : "AANT",   "department" : "Anthropology"},
  {"id" : "AARA",   "department" : "Arabic"},
  {"id" : "AARH",   "department" : "Art History"},
  {"id" : "AART",   "department" : "Art"}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is pointing you to the issue. There is an error in your JSON syntax. The way you are importing the file is fine.

Look back over your file. Or if it helps use a test JSON file where you know the formatting is correct and the error should disappear.